How to reuse the same guard in mpl-candy-machine when minting NFTs
When minting an NFT from candy machine, I want to force users to make multiple payments (so that creators could receive fees from mints).
But it seems like reusing the same guards with candy-guard program is not allowed.
I can use TokenGuard, Token2022Guard and SolGuard at the same time to require 3 transfers, but this forces me to use wrapped SOLs in token programs and, in general, implementing it this way feels a bit too hacky.
Or maybe there is another way this can be done?
